# What is T-Colouring Algorithm?

Tags: ds.algorithms

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but can someone explain in brief what T-Coloring algorithm is and provide a pseudo-code?

I've tried googling it but still cant understand what is it and how to use T-Coloring

Comment: Can you add the references you have checked about the topic?

Comment: this one http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X91902584 and this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-coloring ,still no luck no basic explanation